# How to increase opengl to required specifications

Tags: windows-7

I want to know what is opengl ?

Where i can find it what opengl version in my pc ?

How to increase it to 2.1 if it is lower version. 
Any help or suggestion. Im using win7 Dual core 64bit with 4 GB Ram. I want to install the software called Blender and its requirement is 2.1. 
Thanks

Comment: Can you indicate what you have done yourself to solve this problem?

Comment: If you don't have hardware that supports OpenGL you are out of luck

Answer (score 3):

You didn't tell us what your graphics card is, so this answer will have to be fairly generic, but basic OpenGL support is inherent to that graphics card itself.

OpenGL 2.1 is actually considered a *base standard* that many applications will support. It dates from 2006, so if your graphics card is newer than that it ought to support it.

The other aspect to which version of OpenGL is recognised as being supported is provided by your graphics drivers; so the next thing to do is test is whether they are reasonably up to date.

There is a further consideration, specific to Mac so shouldn't be affecting you, which is that Apple dropped native OpenGL support some time ago, but has maintained support of base-level OpenGL 2.1, so that shouldn't be your issue if, again, your machine/card is newer than 2006.

Some background reading from [Wikipedia : OpenGL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL) but you don't need to understand all of that just to check your graphics card & drivers.